# Systems generators that are not linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening, I would find sets that are generators of vector spaces, but they are not linearly independent, ie they are generating space but are not a basis for it. For example for these spaces: $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$, $\mathbb{K}_n[x]$ .Thanks.

Comment: You can find a basis for your space $V$, and then add arbitrary elements of $V$ to it. I'm wondering about why you want to do this, though.

Comment: This question arises because I read that every generator set is not always basis on a vector space.

Comment: Yes, but usually a basis is better than a generator that isn't a basis. Matrices like $A^\top A$ become invertible if you start with a basis, for instance.

Comment: Is it to say that if I find any basis of a vector space, and then add arbitrary vectors, that will remain a generator system vector space?

Comment: Yes. And all of them can be constructed this way (because every spanning set contains a basis).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39100/discussion-between-daniela-rondon-and-christopher-carl-heckman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the set $B=\{(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$ it is a basis for this vector space, and therefore is a generator system, but as you say in the comments, adding any other vector of the vector space, this set will remain generator system because it contains a base, for example the set $B'=B$ $\cup$$\{{(2,-4,1)}\}$, is clearly not linearly independent, but still generating $\mathbb{R}^3$.